# Unable to start mongod in vs terminal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongod is not connecting with mongo in vs code terminal but when I start it using windows powershell it works fine and connects with mongo.I want to connect in vs code terminal.
Image of the error is attached.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYISB.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error says you don't have `D:\data\db` directory. Mongo by default expects a `data` directory to initialize.

Create `data\db` in your `D` drive.

If you want to point mongo to some existing database the use `--dbpath=<PATH_TO_DB>`.

Replace `<PATH_TO_DB>` with full path to your `db` folder.